# declare variable in if else block in django framework

Tags: python, django

I am doing a conditional block in loop  django template , but unable to find exact answer for this.

Please consider my code here,

```
    {%  for data in app_data %}

      {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
            {% declare_some_variable = 'hello' %}                               
        {% else %}
            {% declare_some_variable = 'bye' %} 
      {% endif %}

      {{ declare_some_variable }} {{ data.name  }}

    {% endfor %}
```

This is what I want. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `with` tag.

```
{% with declare_some_variable = "hello" %}
{% endwith %}
```

You can read more about `with` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Or you can simply do:

```
{% trans "hello" as declare_some_variable  %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it gives error "Invalid block tag on line 104: 'trans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: @Subrata Sure :)  `{% load i18n %}`